# cocos2d-x android develoement - ./build_native.sh giving error in windows 7

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am not able to get rid of this error when I start compiling helloCpp with ndk. I am given proper permission to all users. Please can any one give clue? I included NDK_ROOT also in system variables.

```
dell@dell-PC /cygdrive/C/cocos2d-x/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android
$ ./build_native.sh
NDK_ROOT = /cygdrive/C/android-ndk-r8e
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /cygdrive/C/cocos2d-x/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../..
APP_ROOT = /cygdrive/C/cocos2d-x/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /cygdrive/C/cocos2d-x/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android            Using prebuilt externals
 ++ /cygdrive/C/android-ndk-r8e/ndk-build -C /cygdrive/C/cocos2d-x/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android NDK_MODULE_PATH=/cygdrive/C/cocos2d-x/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../..:/cygdrive/C/cocos2d-x/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt
make.exe: *** /cygdrive/C/cocos2d-x/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

Comment: Please can anyone comment, I am eagerly waiting for comments.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started).
Include these in path and symbols <- C/C++ General<- Properties <- Right Click on Project
Browse and set where you have your NDK Installed.

> /Library/Android/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include
>
> /Library/Android/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include
>
> /Library/Android/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/system/include
>
> /Library/Android/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/include
>
> Under Build->Toolchain Select Android Gcc -> make then reset the 
>   variable under C/C++ build -> build command

reset it to

> bash ${workspace_loc:/YOURPROJECTNAME}/build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1

Don't forget to change the project name in the build command.